# what are node connectivity hard requirements for baking?

Tags: baking

I have an ISP that puts me behind 10.x.x.x but before i learned this i set up a laptop to do port forwarding and upnp and suchlike to bake quietly in the corner.

Since the ISP puts the router behind a private net I cannot do port forwarding or useful DMZ in the simple way as expected.  The first attempt to bake from behind this network had no success for a few days.  Coincidentally returning to my cloud baker setup has also been batting zero once the laptop results were tested.  i was hoping to close this down but i can keep it around for a bit if it proves useful.

the answer found in a discord conversation is as follows:

you do not need open inbound TCP/UDP to bake.  what you need is enough connections at all times.  this has been working from a 10.x.x.x ISP:

: ${TZPATH:=$HOME/tezos};
: ${PARAMS:="--endpoint [http://127.0.0.1:8732"};](http://127.0.0.1:8732%22%7D;)
: ${APIDOMAIN:=services.tzkt.io};
: ${PARLEL:=5};while true; do curl -s "https://$APIDOMAIN/v1/network?state=running" |          jq -r '.[] | .point_id' | sed -e 's,::ffff:,,g' -e 's,:9732,,g'|         xargs -n${PARLEL} |      while read
do  for  j in ${REPLY}
do     $TZPATH/tezos-admin-client  ${PARAMS} connect address ${j} &   done
wait
done
sleep 12h
done

Answer (score 0):

tezos-node needs connectivity to the reset of the Tezos network. This is done over 9732. If your ISP cannot do port forwarding, that's OK, as tezos-node will seek out connections to other nodes as well. Having the port forwarding just makes things easier for the node.

Use the [addpeers.sh](https://gist.github.com/utdrmac/2125a8514960e163837e86bc934f19b6) script in a cron job to run daily to keep your node connected.

Make sure RPC is running on your node (it is off by default) and ensure tezos-baker and tezos-endorser can access the RPC of your node.